# how to put suspension points on a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I'm want to put suspension points as in the picture above. What should I add to the code below?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle, fill=black!70, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1.5mm}]

    \node[roundnode,label=right:{$u^{}_1$}] at (1,0) (u1) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=above right:{$u^{}_2$}] at (0.78539816339,0.70710678118) (u2) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=:{$u^{}_3$}] at (0,1) (u3) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=above left:{$u^{}_4$}] at (-0.78539816339,0.70710678118) (u4) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=left:{$u^{}_5$}] at (-1,0) (u5) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=left:{$u^{}_6$}] at (-0.78539816339,-0.70710678118) (u6) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=below:{$u^{}_7$}] at (0,-1) (u7) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=below right:{$u^{}_n$}] at (0.78539816339,-0.70710678118) (un) {};

    \draw[-] (un) -- (u1) -- (u2) -- (u3) -- (u4) -- (u5) -- (u6) -- (u7);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  By "suspension points" do you mean the dotted line?  If so then `\draw[dotted]` or `\draw[loosely dotted]` is probably what you are looking for.  You can add `thick` or similar to get larger dots.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Excuse me. But I remember that this question is old.

Answer (score 6):

Slightly more complicated than nidhin's solution, add `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` and use

```
\foreach \i in {0.25,0.5,0.75}
    \fill ($(un)!\i!(u7)$) circle[radius=1pt];
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle, fill=black!70, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1.5mm}]

    \node[roundnode,label=right:{$u^{}_1$}] at (1,0) (u1) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=above right:{$u^{}_2$}] at (0.78539816339,0.70710678118) (u2) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=:{$u^{}_3$}] at (0,1) (u3) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=above left:{$u^{}_4$}] at (-0.78539816339,0.70710678118) (u4) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=left:{$u^{}_5$}] at (-1,0) (u5) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=left:{$u^{}_6$}] at (-0.78539816339,-0.70710678118) (u6) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=below:{$u^{}_7$}] at (0,-1) (u7) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=below right:{$u^{}_n$}] at (0.78539816339,-0.70710678118) (un) {};

    \draw[-] (un) -- (u1) -- (u2) -- (u3) -- (u4) -- (u5) -- (u6) -- (u7);

    \foreach \i in {0.25,0.5,0.75}
        \fill ($(un)!\i!(u7)$) circle[radius=1pt];

\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Drawing `dotted` lines is one way to produce this picture. (mentioned is comments by [Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15925/andrew-swann) also.). IS this okay for you?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle, fill=black!70, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1.5mm}]

    \node[roundnode,label=right:{$u^{}_1$}] at (1,0) (u1) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=above right:{$u^{}_2$}] at (0.78539816339,0.70710678118) (u2) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=:{$u^{}_3$}] at (0,1) (u3) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=above left:{$u^{}_4$}] at (-0.78539816339,0.70710678118) (u4) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=left:{$u^{}_5$}] at (-1,0) (u5) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=left:{$u^{}_6$}] at (-0.78539816339,-0.70710678118) (u6) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=below:{$u^{}_7$}] at (0,-1) (u7) {};
    \node[roundnode,label=below right:{$u^{}_n$}] at (0.78539816339,-0.70710678118) (un) {};

    \draw[-] (un) -- (u1) -- (u2) -- (u3) -- (u4) -- (u5) -- (u6) -- (u7);
    \draw[loosely dotted,thick] (un)--(u7);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```